# Solve: T(n) = T(n/2) + n/2 + 1

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity, computer-science-theory

I struggle to define the running time for the following algorithm in O notation. My first guess was O(n), but the gap between the iterations and the number I apply isn't steady. How have I incorrectly defined this?

```
public int function (int n ) 
{
  if ( n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  int i = 1;
  int j = n ;
  while ( i < j ) 
  {
    i = i + 1;
    j = j - 1;
  }
  return function ( i - 1) + 1;
}
```

Comment: To be exact, bit-O is for upper bounds, so there are many possible answers.  For example it is true, but rather misleading, to say that this algorithm is O(n*n).  When possible, it's usually better to use big-Theta to state running times. The analysis in the accepted answer is equally valid for big-Theta.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `while` is executed in about `n/2` time.

The recursion is executed passing as `n` a value that is about half of the original `n`, so:

```
n/2 (first iteration)
n/4 (second iteration, equal to (n/2)/2)
n/8
n/16
n/32
...
```

This is similar to a [geometric serie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Infact it can be represented as

```
n * (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...)
```

So it converges to `n * 1 = n`

So the O notation is **O(n)**

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to write it down as `T(n) = T(n/2) + n/2 + 1`.

The while loop does `n/2` work. Argument passed to next call is `n/2`.

Solving this using the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem%20%22%22) where:

- a = 1
- b = 2
- f = n/2 + 1

[image]

[image]

```
Let c=0.9
1*(f(n/2) + 1) <? c*f(n)
1*(n/4)+1 <? 0.9*(n/2 + 1)
0.25n + 1 <? 0.45n + 0.9
     0    <  0.2n - 0.1
```

[image]

Which is:

```
T(n) = Θ(n)
```